# Data binding seems slow - Audio Meter - Angular 9

Tags: angular, data-binding, agora.io

I'm developing an Angular 9 application with the Agora WebRTC API. I'm trying to display an audio meter, and it works but the template/view updates *extremely* slowly.

If I `console.log` the value during my `setInterval`, the data appears in my console in real-time, works great. However, the template is not updating anywhere near real-time... it's so slow as to be unusable.

The setInterval:

```js
// Initialize the stream
this.localStream.init(() => {
  this.localStream.play("video-preview", {fit: "cover"});
  // Print the audio level every 100 ms
  this.micCheckID = setInterval(() => {
    this.audioInputLevel = (this.localStream.getAudioLevel() * 100).toString() + "%";
    console.log(this.audioInputLevel);
  }, 100);
});
```

The bit of the template:

```html
<div class="level">
  <span [style.width]="audioInputLevel"></span>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to make this `style.width` update anytime `audioInputLevel` changes?

Answer (score 1):

Please refrain from using width property to update your DOM to have better performance.

You can use `transform: scaleX()` instead. This is the most recommended way to update DOM animations without causing performance dip.

This is because your browser will use your GPU to render these!

Also, you can use the `will-change` CSS property to tell your browser that a particular element is going to be transformed during runtime. Although use this [sparingly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)

More on this here:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count

Also, you might want to look into `requestAnimationFrame` as a possible alternative to `setInterval` for better performance. More on this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame